# appending with data attribute in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

How can I append "LI" tag to  "UL" tag  of a DIV with this data-id?

Where should I add UL ?

```
 $('[data-id="car-model"]').append($('<li></li>', {value:1, text:'One'}));
```

Comment: post your html structure to?

Comment: `<li>` elements don't have `value` attributes. That's only for input fields.

Answer (score 1):

You're really close with your code you just have to append an li and then add the ul to your selector.

```js
$('[data-id="car-model"] ul').append($('<li>', {
  html: "Really new item"
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-id="car-model">
  <ul>
    <li>Test1</li>
    <li>Test2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the code your using for appending the ul? Please post your full code in a pastebin.com

Comment: Why should he use the `html` attribute rather than the `text` attribute if he's just trying to set the text?

Comment: @Barmar I got distracted by the assignment of `value:1`, I suppose, in this context, it doesn't matter.  But since he may want to bolden text at some point, I think `html` is a better option.  Nevertheless, edited out.

Answer (score 0):

Get the `ul` within the element by updating the selector(`[data-id="car-model"] ul`) and append `li` to it.

```
$('[data-id="car-model"] ul').append($('<li></li>', {
    text: 'One'
  })
);
```

Comment: @Farzaneh : then get the ul within it

Comment: how can i get that ? i just have the data id of the parent

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140214/discussion-between-pranav-c-balan-and-farzaneh).